# Get IP address on GAE with Flask with ProxyFix

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, proxy, middleware

I have a Python 3 app on Google App Engine Standard.

I was using `request.remote_addr` to get users' IP addresses and it was always returning 127.0.0.1.

I then added werkzeug ProxyFix like this:

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
```

I'm also using other middleware to enable cloud ndb:

```
app.wsgi_app = ndb_wsgi_middleware(app.wsgi_app)
```

Now `request.remote_addr` always returns 169.254.1.1 which is a link-local IP address.

Is there a way to fix ProxyFix to get Flask to return the correct IP address?

The `X-Forwarded-For` header does have the right IP address, but I'd like to get this IP address in `request.remote_addr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like app engine has two proxies.  Don't know what the second one is (one is for the load balancer).

The solution is to tell `ProxyFix` to trust both proxies, and you do that this way:

```
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_for=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it possible request.remote_addr was giving you 127.0.0.1 because you are on your dev environment (LAN)?
2. This doesn't answer your question - but is there a specific reason why you want to use request.remote_addr instead of X-Forwarded-For?

Comment: No, this occurs in production.  Just makes for cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of following options, try both of them to see which one works for you:

```py
user_ip = request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")[0]
user_ip_2 = request.headers['x-appengine-user-ip']
```